# Создание базы yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Почему не создается бд и таблицы в ней (смотрела хейди, и phpmyadmin)? Я сделала yii migration

**файл G:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\test.loc\config\db.php:**

```
return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yii2basic',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'table_Prefix'=>'photo_'
];
```

**файл *_сreate_tables.php:**

```
<?php

use yii\db\Schema;
use yii\db\Migration;
class m160505_055125_create_tables extends Migration
{
    public function safeUp()
    {
    $tableOptions = null;
    if ($this->db->driverName === 'mysql') {
        $tableOptions = 'CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE=InnoDB';
    }
    $this->createTable('{{%album}}', [
        'id' => Schema::TYPE_PK,
        'name' => Schema::TYPE_STRING . ' NOT NULL',
        'description' => Schema::TYPE_STRING . ' NOT NULL',
        'photographer' => Schema::TYPE_STRING . ' NOT NULL',
        'email' => Schema::TYPE_STRING ,
        'phone' => Schema::TYPE_STRING ,
        'date_create' => Schema::TYPE_STRING . ' NOT NULL',
        'date_change' => Schema::TYPE_STRING . ' NOT NULL',
    ], $tableOptions);
    $this->createIndex('name', '{{%album}}', 'name', true);
    $this->createTable('{{%photo}}', [
        'id' => Schema::TYPE_PK,
        'id_album' => Schema::TYPE_PK,
        'name' => Schema::TYPE_STRING . ' NOT NULL',
        'address_photo' => Schema::TYPE_STRING ,
        'file' => Schema::TYPE_STRING,
        'date_add_photo' => Schema::TYPE_STRING . ' NOT NULL'
    ], $tableOptions);
    $this->createIndex('id_album', '{{%photo}}', 'id_album', true);
    $this->execute($this->addUserSql());
}
private function addUserSql()
{
    $password = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash('admin');
    $auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
    $token = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString() . '_' . time();
    return "INSERT INTO {{%user}} (`username`, `email`, `password`, `auth_key`, `token`) VALUES ('admin', 'admin@test.loc', '$password', '$auth_key', '$token')";
}
public function safeDown()
{
    $this->dropTable('{{%album}}');
    $this->dropTable('{{%photo}}');
}
   /* public function up()
    {
        $this->createTable('tables', [
            'id' => $this->primaryKey()
        ]);
    }

    public function down()
    {
        $this->dropTable('tables');
    }*/
}
```

**Скриншот консоли**
http://prntscr.com/b0gedn

Выдает ошибку

> Exception 'yii\base\UnknownPropertyException' with message 'Setting
>   unknown property yii\db\Connection::table_Prefix'

Тип базы данных: `MySQL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В конфигурационном файле config\db.php вместо

```
'table_Prefix'=>'photo_'
```

следует записать

```
'tablePrefix'=>'photo_'
```

Comment: Спасибо, а почему сама бд не создается?   Где прописать создание бд?

Comment: Добавила бд вручную...(через хейди) но только вторая таблица не создается.